# How to update fit method in a sklearn class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I recently started working with GridSearchCV and am not very comfortable with object-oriented programming.

Problem: I have some missing data in one of the predictors and I have a list of algorithms I want to use with appropriate parameter grid. I am wondering if there is a way to create a custom class that would impute missing values in my data different ways before fitting it and try different combinations of attributes for whatever algorithm I am using at the same time. Is it even possible?

Thanks a TON for your help!

This is a class I created for imputing missing values in SQFT column of my housing prices dataset:

```
class Impute_sqft():

    train_X = houses_dummies_copy.dropna(subset=['sqft']).drop(columns=['sqft', 'final_price'])
    train_Y = houses_dummies_copy.dropna(subset=['sqft'])['sqft']
    test_X = houses_dummies_copy[pd.isna(houses_dummies_copy.sqft)].drop(columns=['sqft', 'final_price'])


    def __init__(self, how='random forest'):
        self.how = how

    def impute(self):

        # replace missing values with the ones predicted by random forest
        if self.how == 'random forest':
            houses_dummies_copy = houses_dummies.copy()
            rf = RandomForestRegressor()
            rf.fit(train_X, train_Y)
            pred_Y = rf.predict(test_X)
            houses_dummies_copy.loc[test_X.index,'sqft'] = pred_Y
            return houses_dummies_copy[predictors]

        # replace missing values with the ones predicted by knn        
        if self.how == 'knn':
            houses_dummies_copy = houses_dummies.copy()
            import sys
            from impyute.imputation.cs import fast_knn
            sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) 
            knn_n = 30
            result = fast_knn(houses_dummies_copy[predictors], k=knn_n)
            result.columns = houses_dummies_copy[predictors].columns
            return result

        # replace missing values with the mean for every type of property     
        if self.how == 'mean':
            houses_dummies_copy = houses_dummies.copy()
            sqft_statistics = []
            for house_type in houses_types:
                statistic = houses_dummies_copy[houses_dummies_copy['type_' + house_type] == 1].sqft.mean(skipna=True)
                indexes = houses_dummies_copy[(houses_dummies_copy['type_' + house_type] == 1) & pd.isna(houses_dummies_copy.sqft)].index
                houses_dummies_copy.loc[indexes, 'sqft'] = statistic
            return houses_dummies_copy[predictors]
```

What grid I have for GridSearchCV:

```
param_grid = [{
    'bootstrap': [True, False],
        'n_estimators': [3, 10],
        'max_features': [2, 3, 4]
    }]
```

What grid I want for GridSearchCV:

```
param_grid = [{
        'bootstrap': [True, False],
        'n_estimators': [3, 10],
        'max_features': [2, 3, 4],
        'sqft_imputer': ['random forest', 'knn', 'mean']

    }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to create a custom `Transformer`, and to use it before your estimator in a `Pipeline`.

### Custom Transformer:

Take a look at the template: [`TemplateTransformer`](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/project-template/blob/e588f28c91b3664bc4fc3cc6ae8b38407e319624/skltemplate/_template.py#L136-L203).

A few comments:

- You need to inherit from `BaseEstimator`.
- The choice for `self.how` has to be defined in the `__init__` method of the class.
- To be correct, you need to estimate the statistics during the `fit`, and to apply them during the `transform`. (see also [Why does sklearn Imputer need to fit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691596/why-does-sklearn-imputer-need-to-fit/46692001#46692001))

### Pipeline

To chain your custom imputer and an estimator, you can use a scikit-learn [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline):

- See for instance this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_digits_pipe.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-digits-pipe-py), which chains a `PCA` and a `LogisticRegression` in a `Pipeline`, and then uses it in a `GridSearchCV`.
- You will need to change your parameter grid with the names used in the pipeline, something like

```py
param_grid = [{
        'estimator__bootstrap': [True, False],
        'estimator__n_estimators': [3, 10],
        'estimator__max_features': [2, 3, 4],
        'imputer__how': ['random forest', 'knn', 'mean']

    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer above. Everything works now.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class Impute_sqft(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, how='random forest'):        
        self.how = how

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        import sys
        sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) #Increase the recursion limit of the OS
        from impyute.imputation.cs import fast_knn, mice
        result = X.copy()

        if self.how == 'random forest':
            train_X = houses_dummies.dropna(subset=['sqft']).drop(columns=['sqft', 'final_price'])
            train_Y = houses_dummies.dropna(subset=['sqft'])['sqft']
            test_X = result[pd.isna(result.sqft)].drop(columns=['sqft'])

            rf = RandomForestRegressor()
            rf.fit(train_X, train_Y)
            pred_Y = rf.predict(test_X)
            result.loc[test_X.index,'sqft'] = pred_Y

        if self.how == 'knn':
            knn_n = 30
            result = fast_knn(houses_dummies[predictors], k=knn_n)
            result.columns = houses_dummies[predictors].columns
            result.index = houses_dummies[predictors].index
            result = result.loc[X.index,:]

        if self.how == 'mice':
            result = mice(houses_dummies[predictors])
            result.columns = houses_dummies[predictors].columns
            result.index = houses_dummies[predictors].index
            result = result.loc[X.index,:]

        if self.how == 'mean':
            result['sqft'] = houses_edited.groupby('type')['sqft'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean(skipna=True)))

        if self.how == 'median':
            result['sqft'] = houses_edited.groupby('type')['sqft'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median(skipna=True)))

        if self.how == 'mode':
            result['sqft'] = houses_edited.groupby('type')['sqft'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))

        return result[predictors]
```

```
methods = ['random forest', 'knn', 'mice', 'mean', 'median', 'mode']

imputer = Impute_sqft()
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', imputer),
    ('rf', rf)
])

param_grid = [{
    'imputer__how':methods,
    'rf__max_depth':[1,2,None],
    'rf__bootstrap':[True, False]    
}]

houses_dummies_copy = houses_dummies.copy()

search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, iid=False, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
search.fit(houses_dummies_copy[predictors], houses_dummies_copy.final_price)
```